# Почему «то́рты», но при этом «мосты́»?

Tags: орфоэпия, существительные

Чтобы понять, как ставить ударение в слове, я обычно подбираю аналогичное — по количеству букв, слогов и по грамматическим категориям. Но почему-то это не всегда помогает. Например, **мост** и **торт** — мы говорим **то́рты**, но **мосты́**.
Прочитала, что в русском языке вообще не существует правил постановки ударения и все слова нужно просто запоминать. Правда ли это? И если это так, то почему такие жесткие нормы в постановке ударений?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В русском языке существуют правила постановки ударения, но они не так однозначны, как орфографические правила. Для различных частей речи определены акцентные группы - в частности, существительные имеют 6 акцентных групп.

Слова "мост и торт" относятся к разным акцентным группам. Мост - это в основном группа с постоянным ударением на окончании:  мостА – мостОв. Торт относится к группе с постоянным ударением на основе: тОрта -  тОртов.

А почему так? Это односложные существительные, и фонетически здесь возможны три акцентные группы:

(1)Ударение только на основе: ( знАка - знАков): торт, акт, бланк, вальс, знак, класс, литр, метр, парк, рак, сквер, текст, шанс и др.

(2)Ударение только на окончании:  (дворА –  дворОв): мост, ёж, жук, зонт, кит, меч, нож, ствол, труд и др.

(3) Переход ударения с основы на окончание (рЯда – рядОв): дар, долг, мир, нос, ряд, сад, суп, сыр, шар и др.

Comment: На мой взгляд торт можно поставить в третью группу- слух не режет. В первой группе все слова кроме торт по другому ударение режет а торт нет.